# Does the 25% bonus apply to bux flights?

Tags: pocket-planes

There is the 25% bonus for coins when all the jobs are going to the same destination.  Is there the same bonus for bux jobs?  That is, if I had a Kangaroo full of 4 jobs each of which gave 4 bux, would I get 16 jobs upon arrival or would I get 20 bux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get 16 bucks plus the 25% equivalent in coins for that destination.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for answering.  I did an experiment to check and indeed this is exactly how it works.  The experiment was to stop all other planes and count carefully the bux and the coin reward for a job with the bonus, and the coins came out to include the 25% bonus for what would have been the coins for the bux job.